# Build string into Android .apk but keep out of source control

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How do I take an environment variable at build-time and make it available as `R.string.api_key` at app runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical pattern is to put the string in `gradle.properties`:

```
API_KEY=whatever-it-is
```

If you really want it to be a string resource, you can then use [resValue](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:resValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) in `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    // other stuff here
    resValue "string", "api_key", API_KEY
}
```

(as values in `gradle.properties` get exposed as global variables to your Gradle script)

Or, if you need the value in Java code, you could use [buildConfigField](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:buildConfigField(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
defaultConfig {
    // other stuff here
    buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", '"'+API_KEY+'"'
}
```

then reference it as `BuildConfig.API_KEY`.

And, of course, do not check `gradle.properties` into version control.